Unable to login using Chrome profile
I am trying to use the Chrome profile to login automatically into the Facebook or any other credential site. But for some reason, I am unable to login into the site.
let me share the code first,
    def setup():
        try:
            log.info("setting profile")
            driver, action = setupWebdriver(profile_path="/home/name/.config/google-chrome",profile_name="Profile 12")
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
           
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(e)
        return driver,action



def setupWebdriver(profile_path=None,profile_name=None):
    '''Set up Selenium Webdriver'''
    
    chrome_options = Options()
    if profile_path is not None:
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={profile_path}')
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"profile-directory={profile_name}")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") #For AWS/GCP
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)#, executable_path=r"C:\Users\agney\Desktop\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe")
       
        driver.maximize_window()
        action = ActionChains(driver)
    else:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") #For AWS/GCP/
        chrome_options.add_argument("enable-automation")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)#, executable_path=r"C:\Users\agney\Desktop\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.maximize_window()
        action = ActionChains(driver)
    return driver,action

When I run it, I am able to open a Chrome browser with the account, as shown below in the picture. You can see the profile name "fb"  at the top right.

But when I try to login to some website other than Facebook through it, it just won't login into there. I check the saved password in the browser that Selenium opened, there is no password, but when I did same by manually opening the same profile and check saved cred they are there in the browser as saved.
I have checked the path and all and they're correct.
browser version : 120.0.6099.216

So, I analyzed the root cause of the issue, and it simply stems from the profile I used. If anyone tries to use a particular profile for Chrome:

Open the browser with that specific profile.
Type chrome://version in the address bar.
Use the path specified in the browser's response, as
shown in the image below.


If you're attempting to use a profile that was initially created on a different machine, I would suggest checking out this link: Transfer Google Chrome Profile to Another Computer.
When transferring the Chrome profile, saved credentials will not be included. To solve this, you could first automate the login manually by entering your password and email. Once done, the next time you run the automation, you'll be able to log in to the website.
